# Airflow - How to use macros in a sensor

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to use the Macros in a GCS sensor on the field "object", which is templated according to the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor.py#L23) but it's not working. The UI shows the "object" having the macro as the value.

```
dag = DAG('dag-name',
        schedule_interval="@once",
        default_args=default_args)

date = "{{ ds }}"

gcs_sensor = GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor(
    task_id='sensor-task-id'
    ,bucket='bucket-name'
    ,object='file-name-prefix' + date + '.gz'
    ,google_cloud_conn_id='google-cloud-storage-default'
    ,dag=dag)

dataflow_job_operator = KubernetesJobOperator(
    task_id='task-id'
    ,image='image/path:latest'
    ,command=exec_args
    ,environment=env_variables
    ,dag=dag)

dataflow_job_operator.set_upstream(gcs_sensor)
```

[Object filed result screenshot from airflow UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eelTZ.png)

I tried to use XCom to push the date using a pythonOperator as well, but no success.

Is it possible to use macros in this way or should I try something else?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your screenshot is of the "Task Instance Details" tab, in which case seeing the pre-rendered value of`file-name-prefix{{ ds }}.gz` is actually expected.

If you want to see your template parameters rendered, then you need to look at the "Rendered Template" tab under a task.

Comment: You are right, the value is there. The sensor wasn't working for another reason. Sorry for the stupid question, first day using Airflow. Thanks!